# Swift Inheritance Issue - Cannot access inherited properties

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, swift, xcode6

I'm running into a strange issue that involves simple inheritance in Swift. I might be doing something totally stupid so if anyone has any advice.. thanks in advance!

I am using the latest XCode 6 GM version 6A313.

Here are the 2 Swift classes that's made Objective-C backward compatible.

```
@objc
public class ObjectA : NSObject {
    var testProp: String!

    init(testProp: String) {
        self.testProp = testProp
    }
}

@objc
public class ObjectB : ObjectA {
    var testPropB: String!

    init(testProp: String, testPropB: String) {
        self.testPropB = testPropB
        super.init(testProp: testProp)
    }
}
```

I then initialize and use the object in Objective-C code.

```
ObjectB *objectB = [[ObjectB alloc] initWithTestProp: @"TestProp" testPropB: @"TestPropB"];
// This executes correctly and has the correct value
NSLog(@"%@", objectB.testPropB);

// I then pass this newly constructed object to another class that's written in Swift
AnotherClass *anotherClass = [[AnotherClass alloc] init];
[anotherClass someMethod:objectB];
```

Here is the Swift class where when I attempt to access the inherited property, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS code 1.

```
@objc
public class AnotherClass : NSObject {

    public func someMethod(objectB: ObjectB) {
        // This executes and assigns correctly
        let prop = objectB.testProp

        // This errors out with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error code 1
        // In the debugger, objectB.testPropB actually seem to have the correct value
        let propB = objectB.testPropB 
    }
}
```

Comment: That is about as much Objective-C as one could possibly squeeze into 'Swift' source code...

Comment: Yea.. We are transitioning from Swift to Objective-C so it will unfortunately look very hybrid-ish for awhile.

Comment: I'd test `objectB.testPropB` specifically against `nil` there. Also, are you sure `AnotherClass.propB` and `ObjectB.testPropB` are of the same type?

Comment: I tried to check objectB.testPropB against nil but the act of calling objectB.testPropB gives me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Also, I've eliminated AnotherClass.propB and simply went with NSLog on objectB.testPropB but still no go...

Answer (score 0):

```
var testProp: String!
```

There is no reason for this to be an implicitly unwrapped optional. You always initialize it in `init`. If possible, it should be:

```
let testProp: String
```

If it must be mutable after assignment, then it should be:

```
var testProp: String
```

Fixing this will probably cause the compiler to shout at you where you're doing something wrong (possibly not in the code you've posted here). With a `!`, it is legal to fail to initialize this value (you'll just crash later). Without a `!`, the compiler will better verify that you do initialize this value.

This line:

```
ObjectB *objectB = [[ObjectB alloc] initWithTestProp: @"TestProp", testPropB: @"TestPropB"];
```

is not correct ObjC (there's an extra comma). I'll assume that it's a typo. I don't *think* that can result in a legal C comma-operator that would cause the wrong initializer to run. But maybe... it's at least worth checking if you actually do have a comma in there. (I'm pretty sure `testPropB:@"..."` isn't a legal expression, so this is a little far-fetched, but it would match your symptom).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. You are right, the comma is a typo. I have removed the exclamation mark and the compiler didn't complain but unfortunately that didn't resolve the issue. I think everything else should be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up creating a dummy project to test my theory in a more controlled environment. The fix is basically to ensure that ObjectA and ObjectB are in 2 separate Swift files. When they are in the same Swift file, the error occurs.

Here is the sample code for anyone interested.

https://github.com/MystKnight/swift-inheritance-test

I'm not sure why this is but for everyone out there, I guess limit your files to one class if you are using inheritance...

Comment: It's a nasty compiler bug and you should file it with Apple.  Try adding a couple of methods to ObjectB, say test1() and test2(), then try calling those methods from `AnotherObject`.  If you call test2() you will end up in test1().  If you call test1() you end up in init() (and will crash).